# Mysql query to count how many "1" or "2"s in the whole table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, phpmyadmin

I have a phpmyadmin console Running a voting database where users vote for person1 or person2. the entries then get put into a table with userID, and choiceID. user column is auto incrementing and choiceID is either 1 or 2 depending on what they voted for. this is all new to me and I am surprised I have made it this far. could anybody explain how to make a query that counts how many 1,s , and how many 2,s are inside my whole table at any given time? that would be very awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT choiceID, COUNT(userID) as number_of_votes FROM votes GROUP BY choiceID ORDER BY number_of_votes
```

Given a set of data like this:

[image]

Will result in this:

[image]

Comment: So would i put this in the current php file or??? or would i put it in a new file that runs on the html website?

Comment: You query the database inside your PHP file. I'll update my answer so you can see how to sort by the number of votes.

Comment: I will mark you as the answer, but i will put it in the php script. then how does it get to html? do i just reference to $result in the php file?

Comment: I guess this is another issue. Please open a new question and show us what you did so far, and tell us how you want the data to be presented.

Answer (score 0):

Here the SQL-Command. You just have to replace the tablename.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), choiceID FROM tablename GROUP BY choiceID;
```

Comment: So would i put this in the current php file or??? or would i put it in a new file that runs on the html website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "CASE WHEN" clauses in your query:

SELECT
    SUM( CASE WHEN choiceID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS choice_1,
    SUM( CASE WHEN choiceID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS choice_2
FROM ...
WHERE ...

Comment: So would i put this in the current php file or??? or would i put it in a new file that runs on the html website?

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) from -tablename- where choiceID = '1'

or '2'...depending what you want :P

Comment: So would i put this in the current php file or??? or would i put it in a new file that runs on the html website?

Comment: hard to answer without knowing how your project is structured, for example how are you currently populating the DB ?